# Implementing RL algorithm on apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, reinforcement-learning

I want to run RL algorithm on Apache Spark. However, RL does not exists in Spark's MLib.
Is it possible to implement it? any links may help.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf) or [Pandas UDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf) instead.

Comment: Thank you. But can you explain more how can UDF or Pandas UDF help to implement reinforcement learning on Spark